# How can I echo a new row for each item in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, html, mysqli, explode

I have tried searching other questions, but nothing seems to address this problem. I have an inventory report that displays each product number along with the quantity and the warehouse it is located in. The problem is, some products have multiple locations. Currently, the warehouse numbers are all listed in the same `<td>` element. I am trying to figure out how to create a new row underneath each product to display just one warehouse location per line. The following code is part of a function that is later called in the html to display the results in a table:

```
$total_qty = 0;
        $loc_tr = "";
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_inv)) {
            $total_qty += $row2[inventory_quantity];
            $loc_tr .= "WH".$row2[inventory_warehouse]." ".$row2[inventory_location]." (".$row2[inventory_quantity]."), ";
        }
        $loc_tr = rtrim($loc_tr,", ");
        $total_quantity += $total_qty;
        echo "<td id='originTds'>".$total_qty."</td><td id='orignTds'>$loc_tr</td></tr>";
```

The variable `$loc_tr` is an array storing all of the warehouse locations. I have tried exploding the array but I'm not sure how to echo each item in its own row. Please let me know if I need to include more information in order to get an accurate answer-thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this:

```
while(...) {
   $loc_tr .= '<tr><td>' . $your_stuff . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Put the row/cell tags inside your loop.